# Advanced query running slowly

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Whenever I am running this query, it takes about 25-30 seconds for it to run. As you can see, the most advanced thing here is to calculate two coalesces within subqueries.

```
SELECT
    g.name,
    g.id,
    (
        SELECT
            COALESCE (
                SUM(result2 / result1) * (
                    SUM(IF(result2 != 0, 1, 0)) * 0.1
                ),
                0
            ) AS res
        FROM
            gump.war gwr
        WHERE
            started = 1
        AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
        AND gwr.guild1 = g.id
        AND gwr.winner = g.id
    ) + (
        SELECT
            COALESCE (
                SUM(result1 / result2) * (
                    SUM(IF(result1 != 0, 1, 0)) * 0.1
                ),
                0
            ) AS res1
        FROM
            gumb.war gwr
        WHERE
            started = 1
        AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
        AND gwr.guild2 = g.id
        AND gwr.winner = g.id
    ) AS avg
FROM
    gumb.guild g
ORDER BY
    avg DESC,
    g.point DESC,
    g.experience DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Table structures/schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `guild` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `owner` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `experience` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `win` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `draw` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `loss` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `point` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `account` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `war` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guild1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guild2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `type` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `started` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `winner` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `result1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `result2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: There is no mention of indexes. Do you have them? If not, start there. If that doesn't help much, please come back, but also specify the indexes you made and the number of records and a piece of example data.

Comment: Try to elaborate what you want to achieve with this query. I think then it can be attempted in a different manner to improve efficiency

Comment: @GolezTrol I dont know much about the indexes. Is there any tip on how to add them? Btw. there is not much records though - `guild` has `8000 rows` and the `war` has `1000 rows`.

Comment: Those are not big numbers, but indexes will help. For tips, maybe you should first read what indexes are and how to use them. This is a common subject, and I think creating indexes is an integral part of database design and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes will definitely help, indexing fields used in `JOIN` criteria and in `WHERE` clauses carries the most impact.

Generic syntax example:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_col1col2 ON tbl_Test (Col1, Col2)
```

You don't likely want to just cram every field used into one index, and you likely shouldn't create an index for each field either.

There are many resources for helping you understand how to build your indexes, here are a couple items:
[MySQL CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)
[MySQL Index Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: Its not even better with indexes added: `Query time: 27.773s`. I have added two indexes (first in the `guild` table and the second in the `war` table, indexes containing the `WHERE` clause fields + `SUM` fields.